# Can multiple listeners work on same code?

Tags: java, spring-boot, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I plan to have a broker topic and have multiple default message listeners or simple message listeners. All the listeners execute the same code.

1. Is each listener code execution independent of another. What I am trying to ask is, if there will be a conflict among listeners when accessing the same methods ?

I kind of what them to work like a multi threaded execution. 
I am using JMS and activemq as broker.

Some code to understand :
Each listener will call this method "event processing" sending the event. This method will in turn call other methods. The handle method will in turn call other methods.

```
private void eventProcessing(final Event Event){
        try {
                if(Event.isDatafileTransaction()){
                final EventDatafileTransaction datafileTransaction = Event.getDatafileTransaction();

                            final List<Events> transactions = getDatafileTransactions(datafileTransaction);
                            final List<AcEventRecordOperation> recordOperations = getTransactionsAsListOfRecordOperations(datafileTransaction, transactions);

                            if (recordOperations != null  && recordOperations.size() > 0) {

                                    recordOperationListener.handle(recordOperations);

                        }

                }
        }  catch (Throwable t) {

        }

    }
```

Comment: It is hard to tell without a more detailed code snippets, but the basic multi threading and concurrency still applies to you.
So assuming the eventProcessing method is on a class and being called by multiple listeners and the Event object passed in by each listeners are unique to individual listeners, I think you are pretty thread-safe here

Answer (score 0):

Your listener must be thread-safe - no fields (class-level variables) or they must be protected with synchronization.